# Using related model in scope constraint

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a File model which represents files stored on disk.

The files on disk act as a cache, when a file is requested it is served from disk if it exists, or generated on the fly otherwise.

These files belong to other models using a polymorphic relationship (for example one project can have many files).

The files become stale and must be regenerated if their parent model has been updated since they were generated.

I'm using a scope to retrieve the files related to a model which are still current (not stale).

```
public function scopeCurrent($query, Model $compareWith)
{
    $query->where('updated_at', '>', $compareWith->updated_at);
}
```

I can fetch the current records for a model as follows:

```
$model->files()->current($model)->get()
```

This works fine, but it seems messy to have to pass the parent model to the scope in order to use it. However the scope method runs on an initiated instance of the File model, so it isn't able to access its directly. (Within the scope function, $this is an empty File model with no ID, attributes or relationships).

I've spent a bit of time looking through the docs but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I feel like this article might hold the key, but honestly I'm struggling to get my head around it.

https://nullthoughts.com/development/2019/10/08/dynamic-scope-on-latest-relationship-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your relation looks similar to this.

```
class Model {
    public function files () {
        return $this->hasMany(File::class);
    }
}
```

Instead of going the scope route, why not add another relationship, with a query condition?

```
class Model {
    ...

    public function currentFiles() {
        return $this->hasMany(File::class)->where('updated_at', '>', $this->updated_at);
    }
}
```

I'm not certain this is the correct way, but it felt it was an alternative solution.

Comment: The relationship uses morphMany, but I think that is a trivial detail.  

Yeah, a separate relationship would work just fine I expect. I’ve only recently started making use of scopes and I figured it would be a nice way of keeping the relationships cleaner. I guess it doesn’t really make a lot of difference.  

Thanks for the input. :)